# Google App Engine with .Net Core 3.1 MVC app - Loss of session data between Controllers

Tags: google-cloud-platform, asp.net-core-mvc

I have my server working on .NET Core 3.1 MVC with Cloud SQL - but am unable to pass any data between Controllers. Tried HttpContext.Session and TempData - both go to Null after the redirect.

Has anyone seen this?

Code below:

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

```
        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);                 // Set the session expired time               
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
        });

        services.AddControllersWithViews();

        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

        // Stop annoying startup messages
        services.Configure<ConsoleLifetimeOptions>(opts => opts.SuppressStatusMessages = true);
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseSession();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=User}/{action=Login}/");
        });
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps, the issue relates that the session expired, please check the ConfigureServices method, when you [configure session state](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-5.0#configure-session-state), have you ever set the session expired time? Try to extend the session expired time. If still not working, it is better to share the related code.

Comment: I set expiration for 60 minutes.

Comment: I should mention this works fine when I deploy to a local IIS server. It only fails when I upload to GAE.

Comment: "It only fails when I upload to GAE" If that is the case, perhaps the issue relates the GAE configuration, I think you'd better to contact with GAE forum. From the [Google cloud document](https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/getting-started/session-handling-with-firestore), it suggests using Firestore to handle the session state, you can refer to it.

Answer (score 0):

Closing this for now. I opted to just write to a cookie file directly to save the info.